# How to use Prism within an ElementHost

Tags: wpf, prism, cal, cag

I'm new to Prism and I am attempting to host a Prisim control within an ElementHost.  I seem to be missing something very basic. I have a single WinForm that contains an ElementHost.  The following code is in the form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        bootstrapper.Run();

        var child = bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<Shell>();
        elementHost.Child = child;

    }
```

The BootStrapper handles regisration

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        Container.RegisterType<MyView>();
        var shell = Container.Resolve<Shell>();
        return shell;
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog()
    {
        ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(MyModule));
        return catalog;
    }
}
```

The MyView.xaml is nothing more than a label at this point.

Shell.xaml is a UserControl that contains the following XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Name="MainRegion" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" />
```

The module code is minimal:

```
public class MyModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionViewRegistry _regionViewRegistry;

    public MyModule(IRegionViewRegistry registry)
    {
        _regionViewRegistry = registry;   
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(MyView));
    }
}
```

I've been tracing deep into the Prism code trying to figure out why the View is never set into the region.  Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is this code in Prism:

```
private static bool RegionManager::IsInDesignMode(DependencyObject element)
{
    // Due to a known issue in Cider, GetIsInDesignMode attached property value is not enough to know if it's in design mode.
    return DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(element) || Application.Current == null
        || Application.Current.GetType() == typeof(Application);
}
```

The reason is that for the non-WPF application the Application.Current is NULL!

The solution:

1. Create an empty class that will inherit from System.Windows.Application. (Name doesn’t matter):

At the point of entry to a plug-in execute the following code:

```
public class MyApp : System.Windows.Application
{
}

if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
{
    // create the Application object
    new MyApp();
}
```

This is it – now you have an Application.Current that is not null and it’s not equal to typeof(Application).

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Lindell Above worked for me. The only things I had to change are below.

My bootstrapper

```
 public  class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return this.Container.Resolve<Shell>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            base.InitializeShell();    
            if (System.Windows.Application.Current == null)
            {
                // create the Application object
                new HelloWorld.Myapp();
            }

            //App.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
            //App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
            //MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;

        }     

        protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
        {
            base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

            ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)this.ModuleCatalog;
            moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(HelloWorldModule.HelloWorldModule));
        }
```

and my form class

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Create the ElementHost control for hosting the WPF UserControl
            ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
            host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
            bootstrapper.Run(true);

            //var uc = bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<Shell>(); This line threw error

            //Create the WPF UserControl.          

                            HelloWorld.Shell uc = new HelloWorld.Shell();

            //Assign the WPF UserControl to the ElementHost control's Child property.
            host.Child = uc;

            //Add the ElementHost control to the form's collection of child controls.
            this.Controls.Add(host);
        }
    }   


        }
```

And just to be clear, I added below class in the WPF PRISM application containing Shell.

```
public class MyApp : System.Windows.Application
{
}
```

> Edit: Note that the Load method handler (of form) has to be created by
>   rightclicking form, In the properties window, go to events and double
>   clicl Load. Copying and pasting load event handler doesn't work.